# Spivak, Chapter 7 "Three Hard Theorems", Problem *19d: Understanding the solution manual solution.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Problem *19 from Chapter 7 of Spivak's Calculus asks us a few things.

> (a) Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and let $x$ be any number.
> Prove that there is a point on the graph of $f$ which is closest to
> $(x,0)$; in other words, there is some $y$ in $[a,b]$ such that the
> distance from $(x,0)$ to $(y,f(y))$ is less than or equal to the
> distance from $(x,0)$ to $(z,f(z))$ for all $z \in [a,b]$.

This is pretty easy to prove. The function $d(z) = \sqrt{(x-z)^2 + f^2(z)}$ is continuous in $[a,b]$. Therefore, it takes on a minimum value in $[a,b]$ (this is a Theorem proved in the main text of the chapter).

> c) Show that the assertion is true if $[a,b]$ is replaced by
> $\mathbb{R}$ throughout.

$d(z)$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} d(z) = \lim\limits_{z \to -\infty} d(z) = \infty$. Hence, $d$ takes on a minimum value in $\mathbb{R}$ (this was proved in problem 16 of chapter 7).

**My question is about item d):**

> d) In cases (a) and (c), let g(x) be the minimum distance from $(x,0)$
> to a point on the graph of $f$. Prove that $g(y) \leq g(x) + |x-y|$,
> and **conclude that $g$ is continuous**.

I will now show you the solution from the solution manual (which I don't quite comprehend, so I am asking you to explain it or provide a version of it with less skipping over steps).

**Solution Manual Proof**

By definition, $g(x) = \sqrt{f^2(z)+(z-x)^2}$ for some $z \in [a,b]$.

Now,

$\forall z,\ \sqrt{f^2(z)+(z-y)^2} \leq \sqrt{f^2(z)+(z-x)^2} + |z-y| \tag{1}$

So $g(y)$, the minimum of all $\sqrt{f^2(z)+(z-y)^2}$, is less than or equal to $|z-y|$ plus the minimum of all $\sqrt{f^2(z)+(z-x)^2}$, which is $g(x) + |y-x|$. Since $|g(y)-g(x)| \leq |y-x|$ it follows that $g$ is continuous (given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\epsilon$).

**Comments and questions about this proof**

- I assume that $(1)$ is using some form of Triangle Inequality to say: the distance from $(z,f(z))$ to $(y,0)$ is always smaller than or equal to the distance from $(z,f(z))$ to $(x,0)$ plus the distance from $(z,0)$ to $(y,0)$. The Triangle Inequality I would have expected would have used the distance from $(x,0)$ to $(y,0)$ instead of from $(z,0)$ to $(y,0)$. **Is there a typo, or is it really $(z,0)$?**
- I believe $(1)$ also needs the universal quantifiers $\forall x\ \forall y$.
- With the universal quantifiers, for any $x$, we take $z$ that minimizes $\sqrt{f^2(z)+(z-x)^2}$. Then, according to $(1)$, $\forall x\ \forall y\ \sqrt{f^2(z)+(z-y)^2} \leq g(x) + |z-y|$.
- But we also know that $\forall y\ \forall z\ g(y) \leq \sqrt{f^2(z)+(z-y)^2}$
- Therefore $\forall x\ \forall y\ g(y) \leq \sqrt{f^2(z)+(z-y)^2} \leq g(x) + |z-y|$
- I don't know if this is what the solution tried to explain or not, but it is what I was able to extract from it. If indeed the $|z-y|$ was a typo and should have been $|x-y|$, then one of the desired results has been reached.
- To show that $g$ is continuous the solution manual went from

$$g(y) \leq g(x) + |x-y|$$

to

$$|g(y)-g(x)| \leq |x-y|$$

How did he introduce the absolute value on $g(y)-g(x)$?

At the risk of making this question way too long for some people, I will provide my own solution now.

**My Proof**

Let $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

From $c)$ we know that $d_{x_1}(z) = \sqrt{(z-x_1)^2+f^2(z)}$ has a minimum, say at $z_{x_1,min}$.

Then $g(x_1)=d_{x_1}(z_{x_1,min})$.

Similarly, for any $y_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a $z_{y_1,min}$ such that $g(y_1)=d_{y_1}(z_{y_1,min})$, where $d_{y_1}(z) = \sqrt{(z-y_1)^2+f^2(z)}$.

Therefore,

$$g(y_1)=d_{y_1}(z_{y_1,min}) \leq d_{y_1}(z_{x_1,min})\tag{1}$$

Consider the points $(x_1,0)$, $(y_1,0)$, and $(z_{x_1,min}, f(z_{x_1,min}))$.

By the Triangle Inequality

$$\sqrt{(z_{x_1,min}-y_1)^2 + f^2(z_{x_1,min})} \leq \sqrt{(z_{x_1,min} - x_1)^2 + f^2(z_{x_1,min})} + \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2}$$

That is

$$d_{y_1}(z_{x_1,min}) \leq d_{x_1}(z_{x_1,min})+ |x-y| = g(x_1)+|x-y|\tag{2}$$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$g(y_1) \leq g(x_1) + |x-y|$$

Hence, $$\forall x\ \forall y\ g(y) \leq g(x) + |x-y|$$

Comment: For the last question, simply swap the role of $x$ and $y$ to get $g(y) \le g(x)+ |y-x|$.

Comment: I think you're right. The $|z-y|$ at the end of (1) should have been $|x-y|$, and then the rest of the argument should work (using the comment @Crostul at the end).

Comment: @evianpring Thanks for posting this question and your work. I couldn't figure out what Spivak was getting at.